# fsolve FunEvals per iterations

Tags: matlab, optional-parameters

In `fsolve`, you can set the `MaxFunEvals` to limit the total number of function evaluations. Is there anyway I can set the number of function evaluations limit per iteration?

I would like to make fewer function evaluations per iteration.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but possibly relevant, if your actual issue is time-consumption of each iteration. There may be other factors to consider. Consider vectorizing other parts of your code (if not already)

Answer (score -1):

If you follow [this example as given in the documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html#butbb65-1) it reads as if you want to minimise `Func-count`. It is impossible to *directly* set a cap on that parameter, all one can do is limit either the number of iterations, through `MaxIterations`, or limit the number of function evaluations per iteration, which `MaxFunctionEvaluations` does. The combination of this , `MaxIterations*MaxFunctionEvaluations`, gives the maximum value `Func-count` can achieve.

The `MaxIterations` input argument as per the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html):

> Maximum number of iterations allowed, a positive integer. The default is `400`. See [Tolerances and Stopping Criteria](http://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/tolerances-and-stopping-criteria.html) and [Iterations and Function Counts](http://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/iterations-and-function-counts.html).

The `MaxFunctionEvaluations` input argument says:

> Maximum number of function evaluations allowed, a positive integer. The default is `100*numberOfVariables`. See Tolerances and Stopping Criteria and Iterations and Function Counts.

Comment: I'm not trying to limit the number of iterations but the number of function evaluations per iteration. I'm sorry if this wasn't clear in the question

Comment: @kirikoumath that should be the `MaxFunctionEvaluations` switch you already mention in your question, see the cited docs.

Comment: with `MaxFunctionEvaluations` set to the default value, `MaxIterations = 10`, I'm still getting `Func-count = 3457` on the first iteration. My goal is to limit this value.

Comment: Well, then decrease the number of function evaluations, instead of setting it to default. Also, please edit your question so I can see how many variables you have and what your system is. The literal answer to the (very short) question you posted is `MaxFunctionEvaluations`.